# Tesseract-ocr not accurate enough

Tags: ocr

I am running tesseract-ocr on my Raspberry Pi 2. I have been trying to create a book reader, and I have found that the output is completely garbled. Photo: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-czHHfNjdD9Zk5pZ29pZDloRFhkVzU1aXlUbzY2aGhqa2p3)

I cannot get the output text file currently, but I can probably get it off my Pi later if it is required. It is basically just random characters at the start, then it works until about 2/3rds of the way down the page, then it is a vertical row of random characters, followed by a few more words that make a little bit of sense.

Does anybody have a fix for this? Or any recommendations for a better OCR that can read this type of image with 100% accuracy?

Thanks,

Connor.